# $1.$Find the number of elements in $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

> let $V$ be a $4-$dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z_3}$.

$1.$Find the number of elements in $V$

$2.$Find  the number of $4\times 4$
invertible matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z_3}$

My attempt :  I know the  $2$nd answer will be  $(3^4-1)(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)(3^4-3^3)$
Im confused  about option $1$ How to find the  number of element in $V$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $V \cong {\Bbb Z_3}^4$ and hence $|V| = 3^4 = 81.$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my approach is right or not. if there are any absurdities or mistakes, I am open to corrections. Thank you.

What if we consider the linearly independent vectors of $V$, say $v_1, v_2, v_3$ and $v_4$. Now the linear span of those four vectors is $V$. Consider,
$a_1*v_1 + a_2*v_2 + a_3*v_3 + a_4*v_4$, where $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and $a_4$ are from $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Now, considering the possibilities for the $a_i$, there are 45 vectors, excluding 0 vector. (Like $0*v_1 + 0*v_2 + 0*v_3 + 1*v_4 - (0,0,0,1)$, and $(0,0,1,0)\ldots$). Now switching the possibilities of 0's and 1's with 0's and 2's and then 1's and 2's, there might be 46 vectors (not necessarily distinct).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you.  I shall look into it.